# Extract content of Safari Reader-Mode

Tags: ios, swift, safari

For my iOS application (Swift) I need to extract the content of a webpage, displayed in Reader-Mode (if availible).

1. Provide URL
2. Try to activate Reader-Mode
3. If Reader-Mode is availible -> save all text in a string.

Everything can happen in the background. I don't need to display anything. I just need the content as string in memory.
Any ideas?